# Load CSV with data surrounded by parentheses into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

i need help reading a csv with pandas that looks like this

```
(DATA), (DATA2) , (DATA3)
(1), (2,3), (4)
```

Columns are separated by ',' but also in between () and there are ',' inside some of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `read_csv` with a regex separator.

```
df = pd.read_csv(buf, delimiter='\s*,\s*(?=\()', engine='python')
df
  (DATA) (DATA2) (DATA3)
0    (1)   (2,3)     (4)
```

Now, strip the parentheses from the columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[()]', '')
df = df.replace('[()]', '', regex=True)
df

  DATA DATA2 DATA3
0    1   2,3     4
```

---

`DATA` and `DATA3` can now be converted to numeric columns using `astype(float)`. For `DATA2`, you could call `str.split` and convert it to a list of columns:

```
df['DATA2'].str.split(',')
0    [2, 3]
Name: DATA2, dtype: object
```