# pd.read_csv ignore comma if it is inside parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I have a very simple file:

```
[Name]
Streamline 1


[Data]
X [ m ], Y [ m ], Z [ m ], Velocity [ m s^-1 ]
2.66747564e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.03140453e-01, (0.00000000e+00, 8.17744827e+00, 0.00000000e+00)
2.66958952e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.07407191e-01, (0.00000000e+00, 6.77392197e+00, 0.00000000e+00)
2.63460875e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.06593186e-01, (0.00000000e+00, 7.04168701e+00, 0.00000000e+00)
2.65424699e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00831652e-01, (0.00000000e+00, 8.93691921e+00, 0.00000000e+00)
2.70607203e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.02286631e-01, (0.00000000e+00, 8.45830917e+00, 0.00000000e+00)
2.68299729e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.97365344e-01, (0.00000000e+00, 1.00771456e+01, 0.00000000e+00)
...
```

I need to load the velocity as a vector, into a single row.

My basic code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Marek/Downloads/0deg-5ms.csv", skiprows=5)
```

But this attempt leads to 1st 2 cols becoming index and the rest splits into 4 columns. `index_col=False` can solve the issue with index, but leads to index out of range. I need a delimiter that implicitly tells pandas to ignore whatever is in brackets. I thought [python ignore the separator withing brackets while reading a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087497/python-ignore-the-separator-withing-brackets-while-reading-a-csv-file) might work but yes, I have spaces everywhere. I found some solutions that use extended functions to load files and handle them by lines, such as [CSV file containing column with occasional comma in parentheses crashes pandas.read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55580933/csv-file-containing-column-with-occasional-comma-in-parentheses-crashes-pandas-r) and [Load CSV with data surrounded by parentheses into a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259548/load-csv-with-data-surrounded-by-parentheses-into-a-pandas-dataframe) . I however believe that this is a very easy scenario, as all lines are similar and can be solved by one-liner adding `delimiter='some_regex'`. I however cannot figure out, how this regex should look. It should look for delimiter `,` but not `(.*,.*)`.

I have tried with following, but this results in a single column:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Marek/Downloads/0deg-5ms.csv", skiprows=5,  delimiter=',^(\(.*,.*\))')
```

EDIT: got to something like this - `,|(?:(\(.*,.*\)))`, but this adds an empty column after each comma.

Comment: Consider using `read_fwf` instead of `read_csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After numerous attempts, I have found an answer how to create a very simple one-liner on this. Here it is if anyone is interested:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Marek/Downloads/0deg-5ms.csv", skiprows=5,  delimiter=',(?![^\(]*[\)])', engine="python")
```

Delimiter checks for the comma in everything outside the brackets. Simple like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

You can parse manually the file:

```
data = []
with open('data.csv') as fp:
    [next(fp) for i in range(5)]  # skiprows=5
    headers = [c.strip() for c in next(fp).split(',')]
    for line in fp:
        data.append([i.strip() for i in re.split(r',(?![^\(]*[\)])', line)])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers).apply(pd.eval)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    X [ m ]  Y [ m ]   Z [ m ]     Velocity [ m s^-1 ]
0  0.266748      0.0  0.203140  [0.0, 8.17744827, 0.0]
1  0.266959      0.0  0.207407  [0.0, 6.77392197, 0.0]
2  0.263461      0.0  0.206593  [0.0, 7.04168701, 0.0]
3  0.265425      0.0  0.200832  [0.0, 8.93691921, 0.0]
4  0.270607      0.0  0.202287  [0.0, 8.45830917, 0.0]
5  0.268300      0.0  0.197365  [0.0, 10.0771456, 0.0]

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   X [ m ]              6 non-null      float64
 1   Y [ m ]              6 non-null      float64
 2   Z [ m ]              6 non-null      float64
 3   Velocity [ m s^-1 ]  6 non-null      object 
dtypes: float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 320.0+ bytes

>>> type(df.iloc[0, 3])  # [0.0, 8.17744827, 0.0]
list

>>> type(df.iloc[0, 3][1])  # 8.17744827
float
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems to be correct. However I was looking for a one-liner without using anything besides read_csv, and managed to solve it meanwhile :)

Comment: I'm using the same regex...

Comment: Ah I did not even notice it was the same, you are correct. Upvoted your answer as it is nice and correct, just was looking for the minimalist solution.