# Ignore delimiters between parentheses when reading CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a csv file delimited by | but some of the data includes extra | characters. When this occurs it appears to be only between two parentheses (example below). I want to be able to read in the data into a dataframe without the columns being messed up (or failing) due to these extra | characters.

Ive been trying to find a way to either

1. set the pandas read csv delimiter to ignore delimiters between parentheses ()

or

2. parse over the csv file before loading it to a dataframe and remove any | characters between parentheses ()

I havent had any luck so far. This is sample data that messes up when I attempt to pull into a dataframe.

```
1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1||1||1||||2022-01-03 20:14:51|1||1|1|1%' AND 1111=DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(ABC(111)||ABC(111)||ABC(111)||ABC(111),1) AND '%'='||website.com|192.168.1.1|Touch Email
```

I am trying to ignore the | characters between the parentheses () from (ABC(111) to ABC(111),1)

This sample data occurs repeatedly throughout the data so I cant address each time this pattern occurs so I am trying to address it programmatically.

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541296/pd-read-csv-ignore-comma-if-it-is-inside-parenthesis) seems to be attempting something similar but their solution did not work for me (when changing to |)

Comment: You have a difficult situation.  You can tell the CSV module that your quote marks are apostrophes, which would tell it to ignore the separators within the quotes.  However, that field is ill-formed: it is singe-quote delimited, but it contains unquoted single quotes.  You may need to pre-process this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specifics of your input file you might succeed by applying a regular expression with this strategy:

1. Replace the sub string containing the brackets with a dummy sub string.
2. Read the csv.
3. Re-replace the dummy sub string with the original.

A dirty proof of concept looks as follows:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

test_line = """1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1||1||1||||2022-01-03 20:14:51|1||1|1|1%' AND 1111=DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(ABC(111)||ABC(111)||ABC(111)||ABC(111),1) AND '%'='||website.com|192.168.1.1|Touch Email"""

# 1. step
dummy_string = '--REPLACED--'
pattern_brackets = re.compile('(\\(.*\\))')
pattern_replace = re.compile(dummy_string)

list_replaced  = pattern_brackets.findall(test_line)

csvString = re.sub(pattern_brackets, dummy_string, test_line)

# 2. step
# Now I have to fake your csv
from io import StringIO
csvStringIO = StringIO(csvString)

df = pd.read_csv(csvStringIO, sep="|", header=None)

# 3. step - not the nicest way; just for illustration
# The critical column is the 20th.
new_col = pd.Series(
    [re.sub(pattern_replace, list_replaced[nRow], cell) 
     for nRow, cell in enumerate(df.iloc[:, 20])
    ])

df.loc[:, 20] = new_col
```

This works for the line given. Most probably you have to adopt the recipe to the content of your input file. I hope you find your way from here.